# Validate filenames for multiple files before form submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form where users can upload files. I need the program to check if the file is a PRN and, if so, if it contains the correct docket number and date in the name of the file.  The problem is that a user can upload multiple files at a time.  I have written a JavaScript function to check the filename before the user proceeds, but how do I deal with multiple files in JavaScript?

I have written the function to check the filename, but am at a loss as to how to proceed from here for multiple files.   I am fairly new to JavaScript.

```
function checkFilenames(val) {
        let filepath = val.value;
        let n = filepath.lastIndexOf('\\');
        let filename = filepath.substring(n + 1);
        let d;
        if (filename.contains('.prn') || filename.contains('.PRN')) {
            let docketnum = <?php echo $job['docketno']; ?>;
            d = new Date(<?php echo $job['hearing']; ?>*1000).toString();
            let test = d.split(' ');
            let month = test[1];
            let monthsArray = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
            let numMonth;
            for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if (monthsArray[i] == month) {
                    numMonth = (i + 1).toString();
                    if (numMonth.length < 2) {
                        numMonth = '0' + numMonth;
                    }
                }
            }
            let day = test[2].toString();
            if (day.length < 2) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }
            let year = test[3];
            let dateToCheck = numMonth + '-' + day + '-' + year;
            if (!(filename.contains(dateToCheck) && filename.contains(docketnum))) {
                alert('Please check the file'); 
            }
        }
    }
```

When I check the filenames using alert or console.log, it just shows the first file. Is there a way around this? Would it be better to call a PHP function?

Comment: How are you calling this function, what are you passing in for the `val` parameter …?

Comment: I am calling it using an onchange event in the form. `onchange="checkFilename(this);return false;"`

Comment: Do it this way, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications, and then loop over the files.

Comment: @misorude, great, thank you.

Comment: @misorude, can you please post your answer as an answer and I will accept it? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you best go with the DOM File API here. It allows you to access the file(s) that the user has currently selected in an `<input type="file">` field.

The `files` property of the field is a FileList, that you can loop over like an array. The individual `File` objects in this list offer access to the name, size and type of the file directly. (Reading the actual file content would also be possible using a FileReader, but that goes beyond the scope of what you need here.)

More information on how to use this can be found for example on MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications